# Sorting data in R

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset that I need to sort by participant (RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL) and by trial_number. However, when I sort the data using R none of the sort functions I have tried put the variables in the correct numeric order that I want. The participant variable comes out ok but the trial ID variable comes out in the wrong order for what I need.

using:
`fix_rep[order(as.numeric(RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL), as.numeric(trial_number)),]`

Participant ID comes out as:

118 118 118 etc. 211 211 211 etc.  306 306 306 etc.(which is fine)

trial_number comes out as:

1 1 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17 18 18 19 19 2 2 20 20 .... (which is not what I want - it seems to be sorting lexically rather than numerically)

What I would like is trial_number to be order like this within each participant number:

1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9  10  10  11  11 ....

I have checked that these variables are not factors and are numeric and also tried without the 'as.numeric', but with no joy. Looking around I saw suggestions that `sort()` and `mixedsort()` might do the trick in place of 'order', both come up with errors. I am slowly pulling my hair out over what I think should be a simple thing. Can anybody help shed some light on how to do this to get what I need?

Comment: You are probably using attach(). If so, STOP DOING THAT. Even if they are not factors now, they were either sorted as 'character' or 'as.numeric(factor)' at some time in the past. Show us output of dput( head( RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL) ), dput(head(trial_number)), and if "participant" is an object then we need its structure as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you claim it is not a factor, it does behave exactly as if it were a factor.  Testing if something is a factor can be tricky since a factor is just an integer vector with a levels attribute and a class label.  If it is a factor, your code needs to have a call to `as.character()` nested inside the `as.numeric()`:

`fix_rep[order(as.numeric(RECORDING_SESSION_LABEL), as.numeric(as.character(trial_number))),]`

To be really sure if it's a factor, I recommend the `str()` function:
`str(trial_number)`

Comment: Good answer. Beat me by 49 seconds.

Comment: This is the answer. Doing `as.numeric` on a factor will simply give you the number of the factor label which by default will be lexicographical.

Comment: Thanks ever so much Shea (and all others who posted), your solution worked like a dream!  Looks like I can keep my hair!.. and keep using R. I will get the hang of it all one day!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be worthwhile for you to design your own function in this case.  It wouldn't be *too* hard, basically you could just design a bubble-sort algorithm with a few alterations.  These alterations could change each number to a string, and begin by sorting those with different numbers of digits into different bins (easily done by finding which numbers, which are now strings, have the greatest numbers of indices).  Then, in a similar fashion, the numbers in these bins could be sorted by converting the least significant digit to a numeric type and checking to see which are the largest/smallest.  If you're interested, I could come up with some code for this, however, it looks like the two above me have beat me to the punch with some of the built-in functions.  I've never used those functions, so I'm not sure if they'll work as you intend, but there's no use in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thank so much MikeZ. I tried the solution above and it worked. I am relatively new / light user to R so just getting into writing functions. Thanks for your advice on this.

Comment: No problem!  I just started with R, and have gotten a lot of help here, as well.  All the best :).